# Automator + Calendar: Duplicate events from “Filter Calendar Events” and add to another calendar

Tags: macos, scripting, calendar, automation, applescript

I'm trying to copy a subset of events from one calendar to another, ignoring any recurrences.

Doing a pure AppleScript solution makes it hard to parse recurrent events, but Automator sees through the recurrence to see the event instances that match the filter parameters, so this is the approach I was taking.

How would I create copies of the events outputted from "Filter Calendar Events" and add them to a given calendar? (Don't worry about adding duplicates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if or how an applescript action can handle the data objects passed from the Calendar actions.

You didn't specify what you're wanting to do with the event data, but a solution I suggest is add a "Event Summary"action after the "Filter Calendar Events" action. This will pass a string with all the event details, that looks like this:

```
"TOTAL EVENTS: 2

EVENT 1 OF 2
Summary:    PTO Meeting
Status: none
Date:   1/11/17 to 1/11/17
Time:   8:30:00 AM to 9:30:00 AM

EVENT 2 OF 2
Summary:    MW Board Meeting
Status: none
Date:   1/11/17 to 1/11/17
Time:   1:00:00 PM to 2:00:00 PM
"
```

So, your script action that follows can parse the data:

```
on run {input}
    set eventSummary to input as text -- or item 1 of input
    -- parse the string
    return
end run
```

Again, you didn't specify what you'd like to do with the returned events, so can't suggest what string parsing you need, but should be easy to figure out.

Comment: Okay, I added a quick blurb about what I'm actually trying to do. Basically copy a subset of events from one calendar to another. The summary is a good approach, but how can one convert the summary back to an equivalent event (without some messy string parsing, if possible)?

Comment: Yes, by using clean :) string parsing, along with: tell calendar "MyCal" to make new event at end with properties {description:mySummary, summary:mySummary, start date:startDate, end date:endDate}. You could also do the whole thing in Applescript, but that would stink because "whose" calls to get Cal events in applescript get real slow, real quick.

Comment: Do you also need help parsing "EVENT 1 OF 2
Summary:    PTO Meeting
Status: none
Date:   1/11/17 to 1/11/17
Time:   8:30:00 AM to 9:30:00 AM"?

Comment: Nah, I got it working now. Thanks! Will update this question soon.

Comment: Glad to find a solution for you.

Comment: I ended up using a Run Javascript as js is much better for string parsing. Everything is working now! Thanks for your suggestion, it was right in from of my face haha.